# How to deactivate pyenv virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, pyenv

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 . I installed pyenv following this  [blog](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/).

How to deactivate an acitvated pyenv - virtualenv
I tried following

> deactivate

```
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate must be sourced. Run 'source deactivate' instead of 'deactivate'
```

> source deactivate

```
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate 3.6.9/envs/word_embedding
```

In ~/.bashrc I appended following

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: python already has venv package right? you don't have to install anything to make a virtual env. I use the command `python -m venv venv` to make virtual env with name venv in the current directory.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav Is it possible to use multiple python version in venv

Comment: Seems possible. Whatever python version you used to make the venv will be used to make that venv. So, if you make venv from python 3.7 it'll have python 3.7 and if you make it from python 3.8 then it'll have python 3.8. (I haven't tried it, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681824/how-do-i-use-different-python-version-in-venv-from-standard-library-not-virtua)

Comment: @ Atreyagaurav doesn;t installing differetn version of python affect ubuntu

Comment: No, as long as your main python is just one. the one which is symlinked to `python` command is the main one, you can install others in other command usually like `python2`, `python3.8` etc. If you look at your `python` command it is just a link to the recent version of python you installed. That's why it doesn't matter how many you have installed as long as the main one is same as that required by your system.

Comment: for `pyenv` >= 2.0:
change `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`
to: `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deactivate pyenv in current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348806/deactivate-pyenv-in-current-shell)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and `pyenv deactivate` was not working as well, instead use `pyenv shell system`.

From the [`pyenv shell` docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-shell):

> This version overrides application-specific versions and the global version.

It sets `$PYENV_VERSION` to `system`, and does not affect a `.python-version` file present.

Later, if you want to undo this override, run `pyenv shell --unset`, which clears this `$PYENV_VERSION` environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

`pyenv global system` worked for me.